# Entity Framework - unable to add relation from AspNetUsers to custom table

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In my ASP.NET MVC app I am trying to add a one to many relation from the `AspNetUsers` table to my `Recipes` table.

> After running a migration there's a relation from `Recipes` to `AspNetUsers` but there isn't one from `AspNetUsers` to `Recipes`

This is how I'm defining the model:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public List<Recipe> Recipes { get; set; }

    <omitted for brevity>
}



public class Recipe 
{  
    <other properties omitted>

    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
}


public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<Recipe> Recipes { get; set; }

    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(null);
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

**I have:**

- checked the Recipes table exists in SQL Management Studio (it does)
- tried Googling for similar problems (I'm pably doing the wrong searches)
- run `Update-Database` in the console

Comment: What do you mean by "there isn't one from `User` to `Recipe`"? What's the requirement?

Comment: @Ghukas I want a one to many relationship from the `AspNetUsers` table to  the `Recipes` table...

Comment: If you use Code-First, it should show you the migration code in `public override void Up()` function. Can you please verify that it has the code for the tables you want and contains any info about the PK/FK?

Comment: @Ghukas I am using Code-First and am trying to add the relation by adding `public List<Recipe> Recipes { get; set; }` to `ApplicationUser` and running a migration but no code is being generated to add this column to the `AspNetUsers` table..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@NRKirby, I have used exactly the same code you have posted above, and here is what it looks like in the database:

[image]

I have added `Id` property in the `Recipe` model. I don't know if you have it in the omitted properties.
The code from the migration is as below:

```
public partial class InitalCreate : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Recipes",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    UserId = c.String(maxLength: 128),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", t => t.UserId)
            .Index(t => t.UserId);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.AspNetUsers",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    Email = c.String(maxLength: 256),
                    EmailConfirmed = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    PasswordHash = c.String(),
                    SecurityStamp = c.String(),
                    PhoneNumber = c.String(),
                    PhoneNumberConfirmed = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    TwoFactorEnabled = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    LockoutEndDateUtc = c.DateTime(),
                    LockoutEnabled = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    AccessFailedCount = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    UserName = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 256),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .Index(t => t.UserName, unique: true, name: "UserNameIndex");

        // Some other table definitions...
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        // ...
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Recipes", "UserId", "dbo.AspNetUsers");            
        // ...
        DropIndex("dbo.AspNetUsers", "UserNameIndex");
        DropIndex("dbo.Recipes", new[] { "UserId" });

        // ...
        DropTable("dbo.AspNetUsers");
        DropTable("dbo.Recipes");
    }
}
```

If the result in the DB is what you want, I assume you are running at least one of the commands wrong.

- Enable-Migrations: Enables Code First Migrations in a project.
- Add-Migration: Scaffolds a migration script for any pending model
  changes.
- Update-Database: Applies any pending migrations to the
  database.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer. Can you tell me where in the migration code describes the relation from AspNetUsers to Recipes?

Comment: It's in the `.ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", t => t.UserId)` line.

Answer (score 1):

Any entities that you want to relate have to be a part of the same model.

Find your context class and add an EntitySet for your new type.

Comment: Do you have a property of type ApplicationUser in your Recipe model? It might need to see that before it creates the relation. If it didn't create an id in your Recipe table to point back to the User, then it isn't right.